# how do I remove "permission required" from codename1 apps

Tags: android, codenameone, android-permissions

My latest build now warns me that it needs SMS access, and generally
my builds request the kitchen sink of all permissions. What is the 
protocol to reduce the requested list to what is actually needed?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions that are added automatically on Android map to very specific Codename One API's used by you or by a cn1lib you included the list of the full set of API maps to permissions is in the [Advanced section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) under permissions.

If you've set a permission manually you can remove permissions from the properties as shown in attached image[image]

Comment: Edited the answer to include another option

Comment: Why did my latest build suddenly add SMS permission?